# Monotonic constraints with xgb: increase feature importance of one parameter

Tags: regression, xgboost

I am currently working on a project where i have to deal with monotonic constraints for regression by using a xgb gradient boosting with monotonic constraints and i have a question about this feature.

In my case, I trained my model on my train db (~900 lines) with monotonicity on 3 of my 5 features (-1, -1, -1, 0, 0) --> due to physical meaning related to my data.
On my test dataset, the results are more than correct for a monotonic model (a little bit worst than a NN) BUT when i try do to sensitivity studies (100 times repeated same line of the dataset whith only 1 monotonic feature changed) the impact of the monotocity is very not significant, the model outputs is almost constant **(see on attached picture, red is NN outputs and blue, xgb monotonic output)**

[image: Blue: real monotonic xgb, green: expected output from monotonic xgb, red: NN output]

To precise:

- I took a random line in my test dataset
- I replicate this line to obtain a 100*5 df (100 lines, 5 features)
- I modify the values of my feature (decreasing monotocity) with np.linspace(df[].min(), df[].max(), 100)
- I use predict
- I obtain an almost constant y_pred (other than the first two values, all others are equal)
- By comparing to a NN, the NN outputs a very changing y_pred (but not monotonic...)

So with this problem, the monotonicity added to the model is not very significant, then my question:

Is it possible for training, to tell the xgb model to focus more on a feature than on another. For example, a change in feature 1 of 0.001 induces "more changes" in prediction than a change of 0.1 in feature 4. **The goal is to have a curve for xgb like the green one on the attached image.**

I work in normalized space (value - mu /std), can this have an impact ?

I have possibles solutions/questions, can you help me to say if it might be a good idea or not ?

- I have 5 feature but only one is changing, is it too hard for the model to outputs different values when 4 of the 5 features are constant through a dataset ?
- Will it be more easy to observe a clear decreasing monotocity if i train my xgb only on 1 feature ? The one where the monotocity needs to be applied and after to do a alpha&(1-alpha) combination of NN + monotonic xgb to obtain the prediction ?
- If a applied x^2 or x^3 on my normalised feature, will the increased dispersion of this specific feature will increase its feature importance and then gives a clearer decreasing monotocity ?

Thanks for yout help

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about programming.  It might be better suited for stats.SE.

Comment: No problem, if you think it's not the right place for my question but I'm still interested in solutions, what is stats.SE. ?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/